# How to fix 'LOD code supposed to be unreachable' error

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project in Unity and while in the middle of placing trees, the following errors pop up in the console log:

> LOD code supposed to be unreachable.

The text underneath says:

> UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

The second error is the same except the subtext says:

> UnityEngine.Camera.Render()

I am at a loss as to what this means or what caused it. I looked online and only found 2 obscure inconclusive threads asking similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

The first error message

> LOD code supposed to be unreachable.

has been reported already and is occuring on Unity 5.3.4f1 for my part. However, they already [fixed the tracked issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/lod-code-supposed-to-be-unreachable-error-in-the-console), but according to the ticket it will be in a future version of Unity 5.3.6.

I have read the recent patches and it is not included in any of them yet. I guess we'll just have to wait.

---

Concerning the two following errors, I've seen them as well, but it seems unrelated to the LOD error.

In each case though, it doesn't prevent me from running the game scene, it is just a bit annoying in the console.

> UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
>
> UnityEngine.Camera.Render()